# Ambiguity in pre increment and post increment?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C.I have been practicing some c programming question online,then I came across a pre increment and post increment question.I searched about it all over internet but doesn't find suitable explanation.

```
main(){
 int d=1;
 printf("%d",++d + d++);
 printf("%d",d++ + ++d);}
```

Link for the question :http://www.sanfoundry.com/online-c-test-increment-decrement-operators/
This program is giving different output.In java,It is giving 4.In C, It is giving 5. 
Can someone explain how this evaluating ?

Comment: Oh, and `main(){}` is not a correct signature for `main()`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: **Please** read the info page before posting a question! And don't spam tags. C and C++ are different languages.